# DNSCrypt fails to start (problem with libsodium)

Tags: homebrew

I am using current stable dnscrypt-proxy 1.6.1 version from Homebrew on El Capitan and Yosemite. On either machine I have the same problem.

When run `dnscrypt-proxy` fails with image not found error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libsodium.13.dylib  
 Referenced from: /usr/local/sbin/dnscrypt-proxy  
 Reason: image not found  
./dnscrypt-manual.sh: line 24: 67315 Trace/BPT trap: 5
   /usr/local/sbin/dnscrypt-proxy --local
```

I have `libsodium` installed with the following command

```
brew install libsodium --universal
```

In `/usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.8/lib/` I have the following files:

```
-r--r--r--  1 macraf  admin   763268 Mar  3 12:48 libsodium.18.dylib
-r--r--r--  1 macraf  admin  1091336 Mar  3 12:48 libsodium.a
lrwxr-xr-x  1 macraf  admin       18 Mar  3 12:48 libsodium.dylib@ -> libsodium.18.dylib
drwxr-xr-x  3 macraf  admin      102 Mar  3 12:48 pkgconfig/
```

The problem was also [discussed here](https://github.com/jedisct1/dnscrypt-proxy/issues/245) with no resolution in current version.

It seems `/usr/local/lib/libsodium.13.dylib` is either hardcoded in `dnscrypt-proxy` or the libraries should be somehow linked.

Any idea if there is something wrong on the configuration side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to refresh `dnscrypt-proxy` so that it uses `libsodium.18.dylib` and does not throw the error anymore with the following procedure <sup>*</sup>:

```
brew update
brew prune
brew cleanup
rm -fr /Library/Caches/Homebrew/*
brew uninstall dnscrypt-proxy
brew uninstall minisign
brew uninstall libsodium
brew install libsodium
brew link --overwrite libsodium
brew install minisign
brew link --overwrite minisign
brew install dnscrypt-proxy
brew link --overwrite dnscrypt-proxy
```

<sup>*</sup> credits to [Frank Denis](https://github.com/jedisct1) the creator of DNSCrypt.